Saving TLS connections after an exec in Go
I am writing a server that uses long TCP connections (a mixture of plain TCP connections and TLS ones). Occasionally I would need to update the server software, so I replace the program's executable file, save all the internel state that I need, and call syscall.Exec.
I would want the newly exec'ed server process to hold on to the previous process's TCP and TLS connections.

Naturally what comes to mind for the TCP part, is to save the file descriptors and re-create them, via something like IPConn.SyscallConn to get a raw connection and to use RawConn.Control to fiddle with the file descriptor. However, RawConn.Control says "The file descriptor fd is guaranteed to remain valid while f executes but not after f returns." How do I ensure that the file descriptor is still going to be valid?

How could this be done for TLS? How would I store the ephemeral state?



I'm not sure this is possible -- when working with other parts of Go's crypto libraries I've hit places where state was private and not exported or exportable at all, so you could need to fork them to make it work. Honestly, I'd probably move the TLS termination out-of-process if this were a hard requirement.

Since you can lose a network connection for a variety of reasons and generally must treat them as unreliable, there’s usually no reason to try and do this within a server. An external LB with TLS termination is a much more practical solution.

Heck, move the core application logic out-of-process (f/e, to microservices behind a message bus) and then you don't need to upgrade the component doing TLS termination when you deploy new logic. But as this implies -- the best solutions are ones baked in early in your system's design.

If you have a virtualized clustered environment, 'Live Migration' - already existing feature in products -  moves existing state from one host to another host during maintenance times. The process should transfer the memory state, existing TCP connections to the other host (which is also a member of the cluster).

Contrary to FDs opened to files and "plain" sockets, TLS state is not kept in the kernel: the kernel only provides a TCP socket, and is completely oblivious to the fact it was used to set up a TLS session. In other words, to the kernel, TLS is an application-level protocol. Hence, as Go does not provide any way to "freeze and export" the current state of a TLS conntction its net package manages, you cannot implement what you're after — neither in plain Go, nor using syscalls or whatever. Therefore, what JimB and Charles suggested, appears like the way to go.

@kostix Mhm I understand that TLS is usually implemented in userspace, so my original question is more of two parts: (1) How do I save the file descriptors so I could re-use the underlying TCP connection, and (2) How does Go's TLS routines handle things, how could I make them save state

@JimB It's probably not the most relevant when it comes to most modern programs that use HTTP on top of TLS, but I'm working with IRC, in which, a TLS (or plain TCP) connection represents a user's online state

@RunxiYu, the app doesn’t matter, it’s still a TLS connection. Even if it were possible to do what you want, my point is that it’s a lot of work and complexity to try avoid something you need to handle anyway.

@JimB, no, the protocol is definitely relevant. IRC server and client software are typically written by different people. A user's connection's state depends on the state of their TLS connection; when the TLS connection breaks, the user is removed from the IRC network. IRC servers routinely handle thousands of simultaneous TLS connections for a relatively long time (my last reconnect was 25 November, from restarting my computer). A server that is updating itself would not want to lose all user connections; sure they can connect back, but keeping the connection alive is vital for smooth updates
